# Microsoft exchange connection problem

Tags: gnome, microsoft

Trying to connect to my exchange account with Gnome online accounts. and getting this error "Cannot find WebDVA end point":

[image]

Comment: Anyone has an answer?

Comment: problem solved by installing evolution-ews